# GridView edit command button with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to use the gridview command button (edit) with the jquery not postback. Please help me.

Comment: Then I think you need something like jQuery Grid instead of asp net grid view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Place an asp button in another item template and set its CommandName property to edit. This will work simillar to default edit button in grid view. Then you can call javascript function and perform your logic.

See the code below:

Remove the following line to avoid default edit button:

```
       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"/>
```

Add the following instead:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="headerName" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="edit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in a gridview.What you need is to columns with textbox and display the data in the textbox and needs a button at the end .

```
<asp:TemplateField  >
        <HeaderTemplate>
                    Values                
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:textbox ID"txt" runat="server" cssclass="abc" />        
         </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Spares">
         <HeaderTemplate>
                 Edit column                   
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:button id="abc" runat="server" text="save" cssclass="pqr" />  
                    <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="" />          
         </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Store the Id in a hidden field and it is possible to get the value of text box and hidden feild via jquery.
gridview will be rendered as html table and using `parent()` we can able to find the clicked row and after finding the row u can use `find()` to find the values in the txtbox and hidden feild. Use `$ajax()` or `$post()` to send data to server.